# The rule 'OCLint:ivar assignment outside accessors or init' does not exist

Tags: ios, xcode5, sonarqube, oclint

I am trying to integrate `SonarQube` to generate report on my `iOS project`,

I am using [Objective-C Sonar plugin](https://github.com/octo-technology/sonar-objective-c)

When i run `./run-sonar.sh`

`OCLint` generates a `compile_commands.json` file in my root directory.

and after that getting following error

```
11:24:39.782 INFO  - Processing OCLint report /Users/.......app/./sonar-reports/oclint.xml
11:24:39.899 ERROR - Reporting 1073 violations.
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 16.240s
Final Memory: 6M/86M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: The rule 'OCLint:ivar assignment outside accessors or init' does not exist.
```

Can any one help me on this issue? 
Thanks
AMR

Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. My sonar server had two objective-c code analyser plugin. The [Sonar Plugin for Objective C (free)](https://github.com/octo-technology/sonar-objective-c) and [SonarSource Objective-C plugin (commercial)](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/objective-c/)

When I removed (uninstalled) one of the plugin from sonar server the error stopped to occur

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error too with the last version of this [plugin](https://github.com/Backelite/sonar-objective-c) which is a fork of the one you used.
I downgrade my OCLint version from 0.11 to 0.10.1 and everything work perfectly.
It seems that the OCLint rules defined in the plugin was different of the OCLint version installed on my server.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what version of the objective-c-sonar plugin that you were using.
I solved similar issue before.

Goto `${SONAR_INSTALLATION_FOLDER}/extensions/plugins/`, copy the  `sonar-objective-c-plugin-${version}.jar` to somewhere else.

unzip the jar file, and edit below file
    `org/sonar/plugins/objectivec/profile-oclint.xml`
Add the rule you are missing following the layout of the xml file,
may be look similar below

```
    <rule> 
        <repositoryKey>OCLint</repositoryKey>
        <key>ivar assignment outside accessors or init</key>
    </rule>
```

And edit another file `org/sonar/plugins/objectivec/rules-oclint.xml`

```
<rule> 
    <key>ivar assignment outside accessors or init</key>
    <name>ivar assignment outside accessors or init</name>
    <priority>MAJOR</priority>
    <description>ivar assignment outside accessors or init</description>
</rule>
```

And then using zip to package the files unpacked as the new jar file.
Override the original plugin jar file in `${SONAR_INSTALLATION_FOLDER}/extensions/plugins/`, restart the sonar, issue could be gone.

Repeat the step for all similar issues you encountered.